# Push segue from Cell doesn't work after click

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I have been reading around on various ways to perform segues. I want a push segue from a cell click. I have the segue in the storyboard, so I am not using the didSelectForRow function:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let selectedRow = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow as? Int else { return }

        if segue.identifier == "detail", let vc = segue.destination as? DetailViewController {
            vc.playerImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "userIcon"))
            vc.currentRankingLabel.text = String(players[selectedRow].ranking)
            vc.scoreLabel.text = String("\(players[selectedRow].wins) - \(players[selectedRow].losses)")
        }
    }
```

This is what I have got at the moment. It compiles, but the cell will not react to the click!

Comment: use didSelectForRow

Comment: where did you `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueName", sender: nil)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`indexPathForSelectedRow` is never `Int`, it's `IndexPath?`. Delete the conditional downcast and get the row from its `row` property

```
guard let selectedPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return }
let selectedRow = selectedPath.row

if segue.identifier == "detail", let vc = segue.destination as? DetailViewController {
        vc.playerImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "userIcon"))
        vc.currentRankingLabel.text = String(players[selectedRow].ranking)
        vc.scoreLabel.text = String("\(players[selectedRow].wins) - \(players[selectedRow].losses)")
    }
```

However if the segue is connected to the cell I recommend to use the `sender` parameter which represents the cell

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

     if segue.identifier == "detail", let vc = segue.destination as? DetailViewController {
        let selectedPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell)!
        let selectedRow = selectedPath.row
        vc.playerImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "userIcon"))
        vc.currentRankingLabel.text = String(players[selectedRow].ranking)
        vc.scoreLabel.text = String("\(players[selectedRow].wins) - \(players[selectedRow].losses)")
     }
}
```

**Important note:**

**Be aware that the outlets in the destination controller are not connected in `prepare(for` so nothing will be displayed or the code even crashes.**

Comment: thanks for your answer! But the segue is still not happening....the cell highlights but no movement. I've double checked that I have a segue in the storyboard and that the id is correct.

Comment: Still not working. I used the sender previously when I had a didSelectForRow function, but that was causing the segue to happen twice. The forums said pick one: the storyboard segue or programmatically calling it so I wanted to figure out how to do both. I got rid of the didSelectForRow

Comment: @teachMeSenpai its not working because you not call the segue

Comment: If the segue is connected to the cell the code is supposed to work. Force unwrap the controller `let vc = segue.destination as! DetailViewController` to exclude a design mistake. And is the identifier correct?

Comment: I've delete the segue and put a new one but I'm still getting an error. I dragged from the cell to the next VC and named the id "detail". I'm now getting this error:

            vc.currentRankingLabel.text = String(players[selectedRow].ranking)

Unexpectedly found nil

Comment: See my *important note*. You have to declare temporary properties in the destination controller, assign the values to those properties in `prepare(for` and assign the values to the outlets in `viewDidLoad()` of the destination controller.

Comment: Bingo! I think that was it. I will check and see now

Comment: It worked! But now the segue is happening twice again...the first one doesn't pass the values but the second one has the right data

Comment: Have you still implemented `didSelectRowAt`? Delete the entire method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need call `performSegue` on cell selection, like below

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detail", sender: indexPath)
    }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     guard let selectedPath = sender as? IndexPath, let selectedRow = selectedPath.row, let player = players[selectedRow] else {
        return
     }
     if segue.identifier == "detail", let vc = segue.destination as? DetailViewController {
        vc.playerImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "userIcon"))
        vc.currentRankingLabel.text = String(player.ranking)
        vc.scoreLabel.text = String("\(player.wins) - \(player.losses)")
     }
}
```

Comment: Your already send indexPath  `sender: indexPath`, why you do  `let selectedPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell)!
        let selectedRow = selectedPath.row` ?

Comment: I'm getting a "Could not cast value of type 'NSIndexPath' (0x1d07ad610) to 'UITableViewCell' " error with this code.

Comment: If the segue is connected to the cell the segue **is** going to be called.

Comment: @vadian how you know that segue is connected to the cell? He only said "I have the segue in the storyboard"

Comment: but we need to call performSegue

Comment: the new code is now giving me a "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" at the             

vc.currentRankingLabel.text = String(players[selectedRow].ranking)

Comment: @teachMeSenpai, All the optionals are added in guard let to avoid optional errors

Comment: but there should be no optional. I manually initialized that variable to a 5 in the constructor


players = [Player(
            userId: "abcdef",
            ladderId: 1,
            name: "Kobe Bryant",
            photoUrl: nil,
            score: 50,
            ranking: 5,
            wins: 30,
            losses: 20)]

Comment: I have updated the answer, can you please try that one

Comment: @Bappaditya The crash occurs because the outlets are not connected yet in `DetailViewController`. The `guard`ing is not necessary.